# Azure DevOps Pipelines with Ansible playbook not saving environment variables

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up an Azure DevOps Pipeline using the `azure-pipelines.yml` file below. My intent is simply to set up a python environment on the managed node via an ansible playbook `playbook.yml` (below). The playbook should be able to run in the pipeline or to manage nodes by being run separately from the pipeline. I'd like `pyenv` to manage python versions; I intend to use `venv` to manage virtual environments after.

I wrote down two "versions" of the ansible playbook. In the first, I attempt to follow instructions on the [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv?tab=readme-ov-file#installation) website. They work when running the playbook on my local machine. However, they do not work when trying to run the azure devops pipeline. I get the error that the command `pyenv` is not found, and I believe this is because the environment variables set in the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are not saved or do not take effect. Running "version 2" works, but the downfall is that I'd have to do everything with one shell script, rather than breaking the playbook into separate tasks, making it more modular and useful for future edits.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
# azure-pipelines.yml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest #  macOS-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python310:
      python.version: '3.10'

steps:
  - shell: |
      echo python --version
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python -m pip install ansible
    displayName: 'Update pip and install ansible'

  - shell: |
      echo "Python version: $(python.version)"
      ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars "python_version=$(python.version)"
    displayName: 'Run ansible playbook'
```

```
# playbook.yml

---
- name: Setup development environment
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_shell_executable: /bin/bash
    pyenv_root: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.pyenv"
    python_version: "{{ python_version }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Download and install Pyenv
      become: true
      shell: git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git {{ pyenv_root }}
      args:
        creates: "{{ pyenv_root }}"

    #----------------     VERSION 1     ----------------

    - name: Edit .bashrc environment variables
      become: true
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc"
        line: |
          export PYENV_ROOT="{{ pyenv_root }}"
          command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
          eval "$(pyenv init -)"
          source "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bashrc"

    - name: Edit .bash_profile environment variables
      become: true
      lineinfile:
        path: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bash_profile"
        line: |
          export PYENV_ROOT="{{ pyenv_root }}"
          [[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
          eval "$(pyenv init -)"
          source "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.bash_profile"

    - name: Update shell
      shell: exec "$SHELL"

    - name: try pyenv
      shell: pyenv --version

    # Error: /bin/bash command not found: pyenv.

    #---------------------------------------------------

    #----------------     VERSION 2     ----------------

    - name: All at once
      become: true
      shell: |
        export PYENV_ROOT="{{ pyenv_root }}"
        export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
        eval "$(pyenv init -)" 
        pyenv --version
      register: pyenvversion
    - debug:
        msg: Got here. Pyenv version is "{{ pyenvversion }}".

    # Success.

    #---------------------------------------------------
```